# $f_{*}$ is surjective if and only if $f$ is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

*I’m having trouble proving the following theorem. I’ll show my proof so far. I would really appreciate if you could **help** me, so I can **improve my proof and correct some mistakes**.*

> **Theorem:** Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a map. Think of this map as inducing the map $f_{*}:\mathcal{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)$, and the map $f^{*}:\mathcal{P}(B) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$. Then, $f_{*}$ is surjective if and only if $f$ is surjective.

> **Proof:** $\implies.$ Suppose that $f_{*}$ is surjective. Then, for all $Y \subseteq B$, there exists some $X \subseteq A$, such that $f_{*}(X)=Y$. In particular, for $Y=B$, there is some set $X \subseteq A$, such that $f_{*}(X)=B$. Let $X_0$ be that set. Since $X_{0} \subseteq A$, we know that $f_{*}(X_{0}) \subseteq f_{*}(A)$. Observe that $f_{*}(A) \subseteq B$. Given that $f_{*}(X_{0}) = B$, then $f_{*}(X_{0}) \subseteq B$. From $f_{*}(X_{0}) \subseteq f_{*}(A)$ we conclude that $B \subseteq f_{*}(A)$. So we have that $f_{*}(A)=B$, therefore $f$ is surjective.
>
> $\Longleftarrow.$ Suppose that $f$ is surjective. From a former theorem, I know that $F = f_{*}(f^{*}(F))$ for all $F \subseteq B$. Let $S \subseteq B$ be any set. Observe that $S \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. We define the set $R \subseteq A$ as $R=f^{*}(S)$. Note that $R \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. So $f_{*}(R) = f_{*}(f^{*}(S)) = S$. Therefore $f_{*}$ is surjective. $\square$

**Is this proof right? I think this could be better and I want to improve it! Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance!**

Comment: As all the answers below pointed out, your proof for the direct implication is essentially correct. As for the reverse implication, your proof could be considerably expedited by remarking that $f_{*}\circ f^{*}=\mathbf{1}_{\mathscr{P}(B)}$, which automatically entails the surjectivity of $f_{*}$, by virtue of the general proposition: given two maps whose composition is surjective (injective), the left (right) factor of this composition is necessarily surjective (injective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$\implies$" part is very well written, but you introduced $X_0$ and kept writing it as $X$

For the "$\Longleftarrow$" part, $f_*(f^*(R))$ is not defined, since $R\in \mathcal P(A)$, and nothing implies that $R\in \mathcal P(B)$ or $f_{*}(f^{*}(R)) = f_{*}(f^{*}(S))$ . However, correcting this detail and writing $f_*(R)=f_*(f^*(S))=S$ will do.

It seems that the only mistakes are in the notation, and besides that the proof is ok.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, I really appreciate it. Indeed the second part has a mistake. I’m correcting it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is more or less correct. There are a couple of inconsistencies that I'll point out below.

For the direction $\Longrightarrow$, at some point you defined $X_0$ but then never used it again. Insetead you used simply $X$. Other than that, your argument for this direction is correct.

For the reverse direction $\Longleftarrow$, you define $R=f^*(S) \subset A$ and at some point you write $f_*(f^*(R))$, which doesn't make much sense because $f^*: \mathcal{P}(B) \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ and $R \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. What you probably meant is to write
$$
f_*(R)=f_*(f^*(S))=S.
$$
After fixing this issue, your argument is correct.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning in general $f_*$ is also written by $f$ (this is a well accepted abuse of notation in the literature) and $f^{*}$ is commonly written as $f^{-1}$.

Comment: For the fist part, I forgot to keep the $X_0$ notation. For the second part, what you said in the end is exactly what I meant to write but for some reason I made that mistake! I’m fixing these errors, and thank you so much for the feedback! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome!